# Baby Rudin theorem 10.33 ( STOKES' THEOREM)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The definitions which we need for the proof of the theorem.
We define the standard simplex $Q^k$ to be the set of all $u$ $\in$ $R^k$ of the form
$u$ = $\sum_{i=1}^k$ $\alpha_i$ $e_i$.

Assume now that $p_0$, $p_1$,...$p_k$ are points of $R^n$.

The oriented affine $k$-simplex
$\sigma$ $=$ [$p_0$, $p_1$,...$p_k$] is defined to be the $k$-surface in $R^n$ with parameter domain $Q^k$ which is given by the affine mapping
$\sigma$($\sum_{i=1}^k$ $\alpha_i$ $e_i$) $=$ $\sigma(u)$ $=p_0$ + $\sum_{i=1}^k$ $\alpha_i$($p_i$ - $p_0$).
Note that $\sigma$ is characterized by
$\sigma(0)$ = $p_0$, $\sigma(e_i)$ = $p_i$  (for $1$ $\leq$ $i$ $\leq$ $k$).

For $k$ $\geq$ $1$, the boundary of the oriented affine $k$-simplex

$\sigma$ $=$ [$p_0$, $p_1$,...$p_k$]
is defined to be the affine ($k-1$)-chain

$\partial$$\sigma$ = $\sum_{j=0}^k$ $(-1)^j$[$p_0$,...,$p_{j-1}$,$p_{j+1}$,..,$p_k$].
For $1$ $\leq$ $j$ $\leq$ $k$, observe that the simplex $\sigma_j$ = [$p_0$,...,$p_{j-1}$,$p_{j+1}$,..,$p_k$] has $Q^{k-1}$ as its parameter domain and that is defined by

$\sigma_j(u)$ = $p_0$ + $Bu$ ( $u$ $\in$ $Q^{k-1}$)

The class $\mathscr C'$ means the class of  continuously differentiable functions and etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

$x_j$ = ${ \begin{cases} {u_j (1 \leq j \lt r),} \\ {1 - (u_1 + ... + u_{k-1})  (j=r),} \\ {u_{j-1}  (r \lt j  \leq k). }  \end{cases} } $

( this is $(98)$).

$x_j$ = ${ \begin{cases} {u_j (1 \leq j \lt i),} \\ { 0  (j=i),} \\ {u_{j-1}  (i \lt j  \leq k). }  \end{cases} } $  .

( this is $(99)$).

I dont'understand how do we get the $(98)$ and $(99)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should write what is $Q^{k-1}$ and how $[e_1,e_2,\dots,e_k](\mathbf{u})$ ist defined as a map.

Comment: @hal4math Check it. I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have  $x = \tau_0(u) = e_r + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i(p_i - e_r)$. So if $1 \leq j < r$, then you get

$$x_j = \left(e_r + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i p_i -\sum_{i=1}u_i e_r\right)_j = u_j,$$

since for $j < r$ we have $p_j = e_j$. However, for $j > r$ we have $p_{j-1} =
e_{j}$, so that in that case

$$x_j = \left(e_r + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i p_i -\sum_{i=1}u_i e_r\right)_j = u_{j-1}.$$

For the case $j=r$, it is

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_j &= \left(e_r + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i p_i -\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i e_r\right)_j 
\\
&= \left(e_r + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i p_i -\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i e_r\right)_j
\\
&= \left(e_r  -\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i e_r\right)_j
\\
&= \left((1 -\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i) e_r\right)_j
\\
&= 1 -\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i.
\end{aligned}
$$

Hope that helps!

Comment: sorry I don't understand how did you get $u_j$ in the fist line. please explain it more explicitly.

Comment: You have $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} u_i p_i = u_1p_1 + \dots u_{r-1}p_{r-1} + \dots u_{r}p_{r} +\dots u_{k-1}p_{k-1}$. So plugging in the $p_i$s you get  $u_1e_1 + \dots u_{r-1}e_{r-1} + \dots + u_{r}e_{r+1} +\dots + u_{k-1}e_{k}$. There you see that the $j$-th component is $u_j$. Notice that I should not have summed up to $k$ but only $k-1$.

Comment: the j-th component is $u_j$$e_j$ . and why are the other other components equal of zero? @hal4math

Comment: They are not zero, but they are not in the j-th component? Also the $j$-th component is $u_j$ and not $u_j e_j$. That is still a vector.

Comment: okay I get it. but could you tell why is it still a vector?

Comment: $e_j$ is a vector and $u_j$ is a real number, so $u_je_j$ is also vector. Or am I missing your question?